# How can i conditionally display an element using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, key-value

I want to display an element conditionally based on the value of another parameter PaymentTypeid. After setting the condition as below the element Payment Channel is not rendering in the UI:

```
                <tr ng-init="paymentMode='BANK CABS'" ng-if="json.name == 'paymentTypeId' &&  json.property == '1'">
                    <td><strong>{{ 'label.heading.paymentchannel' | translate }}:</strong></td>
                    <td ><span >{{paymentMode}} </span></td>
                </tr>
```

However when i refactor the markup as below the element is showing as [image: here] :

```
<tr ng-init="paymentMode='BANK CABS'">
                        <td><strong>{{ 'label.heading.paymentchannel' | translate }}:</strong></td>
                        <td ><span >{{paymentMode}} </span></td>
                    </tr>
```

PaymentTypeId is in a json array defined as follows in the controller:

```
scope.details = {};
        resourceFactory.auditResource.get({templateResource: routeParams.id}, function (data) {
            scope.details = data;
            scope.details.paymentMode="";
            scope.commandAsJson = data.commandAsJson;
            var obj = JSON.parse(scope.commandAsJson);
            scope.jsondata = [];
            _.each(obj, function (value, key) {
                scope.jsondata.push({name: key, property: value});
            });
        });
```

In the view PaymentTypeid renders as :

```
<table class="table" data-ng-show="details.commandAsJson" data-anchor>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="json in jsondata">
                        <td class="width20"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{json.name}}</strong></td>
                        <td class="width80">{{json.property}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Any insight on what i might be getting wrong. Im not entirely sure between using ng-if/ng-show or whether im setting json.property correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have knowledge of **scope** in **AngularJS**.

There is a difference between using `ng-if` and `ng-show`. Whenever you use `ng-if` , it creates it own **child scope**. and you can manage it in custom directive that deals with its **child scope** (child scope is not available in controller unless you write your code in a way, that will make it available in controller) and you can hack the scope to use it in **controller** too. But that is not the case in `ng-show`.

When you use `ng-show` it will not remove your HTML from the **DOM tree** but if you use `ng-if` it will also remove your html from **DOM tree**. (To assist your confusion which one to use)

You have a scope issue here , if i'm getting it right. Use `ng-show` and it will work.

```
<div ng-show="condition">
 your html markup
 </div>
```